# Return a column to notify row change of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
|----fruit----|
|-------------|
|--Apples--|
|--Apples--|
|--Apples--|
|--Apples--|
|-bananas-|
|-bananas-|
|-oranges-|
|--plums---|
|--plums---|
```

I have the below script:

```
case when
[fruit] = [fruit] then '0'
else [fruit]
end
```

what I want to do is return two columns.
1 is the fruit column and the 2nd is a column that shows when the fruit column changes to the next fruit, so i have something like the following:-

```
|----fruit----||fruit change|
|-------------||----------------|
|--Apples--||-------0-------|
|--Apples--||-------0-------|
|--Apples--||-------0-------|
|--Apples--||-------0-------|
|-bananas-||--bananas--|
|-bananas-||-------0-------|
|-oranges-||---oranges---|
|--plums---||----plums----|
|--plums---||-------0-------|
|--plums---||-------0-------|
|--plums---||-------0-------|
|--plums---||-------0-------|
|--mango---||---mango---|
|--mango---||-------0-------|
```

How do i return the column corresponding to the change in fruit as my script above doesn't allow me to specify what I need it to do.

Comment: Your sample data has no way to order the data. And it is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Can you post some ddl [create table statement(s)] and some sample data as inserts? Then explain the desired output?

Comment: Kind of unclear where you're heading with this

Comment: Also, tell us what version of sql server, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lag as below:

```
Select fruit,case when fruit <> lag(fruit) over(order by id) then fruit else '0' end as fruitChange 
    from #data
```

Output as below:

```
+---------+-------------+
|  fruit  | fruitChange |
+---------+-------------+
| Apples  | 0           |
| Apples  | 0           |
| Apples  | 0           |
| Apples  | 0           |
| bananas | bananas     |
| bananas | 0           |
| oranges | oranges     |
| plums   | plums       |
| plums   | 0           |
+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: You've made two bold assumptions here. 1) that the OP is using 2012+ and 2) that there is an ID column which isn't listed in the question.

Comment: :) Agreed, Expecting OP to provide those info if not they can come back...

Comment: This works for me, I switched ID out with another key column. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Version with first row display fruit, not 0.

```
-- create table 
create table #data (id int identity(1,1), fruit nvarchar(20))
go

-- insert 
insert into #data 
values ('apple'),('apple'),('apple'),('ban'),('ban'),('orange'),('orange'),('orange'),('orange'),('lime'),('lime'),('lime'),('lime'), ('steak')
go

-- select, note first row will give you fruit as well 
Select *,
    case when fruit <> lag(fruit) over(order by id) 
            or lag(fruit) over(order by id) is null then fruit
        else '0' 
    end as value
from #data
```

Output:

```
id  fruit   value
1   apple   apple
2   apple   0
3   apple   0
4   ban     ban
5   ban     0
6   orange  orange
7   orange  0
8   orange  0
9   orange  0
10  lime    lime
11  lime    0
12  lime    0
13  lime    0
14  steak   steak
```

Comment: You've made two bold assumptions here. 1) that the OP is using 2012+ and 2) that there is an ID column which isn't listed in the question

Comment: @sscimon, my bad, there is many things not listed in the question..., if answer won't suit OP, simple won't accept it